# wrong output for assert in junit test case for exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, exception

```
public class xyzException extends Exception{
    private final Object mSource;
    private final Object mObjectInError;
    private final Throwable mCause;

    public xyzException(Object obj1, Object obj2, Throwable cause, String message){
        super(message);
        this.mSource = obj1;
        this.mObjectInError = obj2;
        this.mCause = cause;
    }

    public static String getStackTrace(xyzException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(w);
        try {
            w.close();
        } 
        catch (final Exception ignore) {
        }
        return sw.toString();
    }
```

I have written this test case in junit for getStackTrace() method:

```
public class xyzExceptionTest {
        private String message;
        private String source;
        private xyzException obj;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            message = "Exception";
            source = "source";
            obj = new xyzException(source, "MyObject.class", new NullPointerException(), message);
        }
        @Test
        public void getStackTraceTest() {
            assertEquals("GetStackTrace unexpected Value", "MyObject.class",xyzException.getStackTrace(obj));
        }
}
```

But this is getting failed. how can i correct it and the reason for its failure?
The error is assert is getting exceptions.
How should i avoid that.

Comment: Edited assertEquals with proper method..

Comment: I see. The code here is full of "lil mistakes". E.g., it doesn't compile, because there are no fields `mSource`, `mObjectInError` and `mCause`. They seem insignificant as they are unused. Should they have been used?

Comment: The problem boils down to why you'd expect the `new NullPointerException().printStackTrace()` call to return "MyObject.class". What exactly is what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It is compiling correctly as i have just put the main part of code. 
I will edit and declare mObject,mSource.
I was trying to see how it behaves when used with exceptions. 
On s.o.p the above method returns MyObject.class. I am trying to figure out but it gives unusual error.

Comment: Why are you expecting that the xyzException.getStackTrace return the mObjectInError? According to your code it should return the invocation of printStackTrace on the passed exception. All of this should end on the call of printStackTrace of Throwable class [Docu of Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) which behave quite different of what you expect

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code somewhat to show you that there's nothing exceptional. No functional changes, I only removed dead code. The code then boils down to this:

```
public class XyzException extends Exception {

    public static String getStackTrace(XyzException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
            e.printStackTrace(w);
            return sw.toString();
        } 
    }

    public XyzException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class XyzExceptionTest {
    private String message;
    private XyzException exception;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        message = "A message";
        exception = new XyzException(message);
    }

    @Test
    public void getStackTraceTest() {
        System.out.println(XyzException.getStackTrace(obj));
        assertEquals("GetStackTrace unexpected Value", "MyObject.class", XyzException.getStackTrace(exception));
    }
}
```

Now, you can see that the `XyzException` class is nothing now, it just calls the parent constructor with a passed `message`, nothing else.

The static `getStackTrace(XyzException e)` method also does nothing fancy. It takes the passed exception and returns its stack trace as one long String. On my setup, that stack trace looks like this:

> ```
> cz.slanec.playground.XyzException: A message
>     at cz.slanec.playground.XyzExceptionTest.setUp(XyzExceptionTest.java:15)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
> ```

Why on Earth would you expect `"MyObject.class"` to show up anywhere in there? The code works as it should, see e.g. [`Throwable#printStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29).

Start from scratch, define your class and the intended behaviour, then write the tests to verify said behaviour. Right now, the test is flat out wrong.